# MVC3 Pass Model view to controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to pass model from view to controller using javascript. But it returns null values.

Here is my view
**Newcamp.chstml**

```
 <input type="submit" value="Preview" id="ClickMe" class="cssLoginButton blue"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function OpenWindow(query, w, h, scroll) {
     var l = (screen.width - w) / 2;
     var t = (screen.height - h) / 2;

     winprops = 'resizable=0, height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top=' + t + ',left=' + l + 'w';
     if (scroll) winprops += ',scrollbars=1';
     var f = window.open(query, "_blank", winprops);
 }


 $(function () {
     $('#ClickMe').click(function () {
             OpenWindow('@Url.Action("NewCampEmail", "Camp",new{model = @Model})', 700, 700, true);
     });
 });
</script>
```

My controller action **NewCampEmail**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult NewCampEmail(Models.NewCamp model)
    {            
        return ReturnModelWithEmailType(model,EmailType.NewCampEmail);
    }
```

In **model** I get null values. Why I am getting null values? Is there any change in my code? My model is same in **NewCamp.chstml** i.e. Models.Newcamp

Comment: is your model to be passed to controller the same as what you have passed from controller to view? If you're passing only model from view to controller without previously passed model from controller to view then you are destroying the MVC pattern as it behaves by passing model from controller to view not passing model from view to controller.

Comment: @jobert thank you for reply. I have passed same model to view

Comment: If you want to pass some array or some collection to a controller as parameters use Json instead

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass the @Model via javascript in this way. the Model ONLY exists on the serverside and is used in page creation ahead of the http response sending it back. You can of course get 'values' from the model and sent them as contants to the controller but there's no way to reference the actual Model per-se in this way.

Your best bet would be to look at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) (a great excercise irrespective) or similar if you want to refer to a single `Model`, rather than properties on the page etc.

In a nutshell, once the page has been rendered, the @Model is gone and can only be referenced via page properties or javascript objects populated by the @Model...