# MVC4 passing all form data (model) from javascript to controller -- is it possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The reply at

[MVC3 Pass Model view to controller using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275461/mvc3-pass-model-view-to-controller-using-javascript)

implies that this was impossible, at least for MVC 3.

I was wondering if there is any way in MVC 4 to quickly pass the entire form contents (represented by the model) from the .cshtml (razor) view to the controller in JavaScript.

For example, if I select a dropdown, I may want to return all fields from a form to the controller which will take appropriate action.

Obviously, for large forms it is undesirable to have to do this element-by-element

Comment: Why is it impossible (on MVC 3)? I do it all the time. Have you ever heard about `JSON`, `AJAX`, `Serialization`, `JsonNET`, etc? Actually, you don't pass anything. You submit information to an `Action` in the `Controller`.

Comment: Do you have a small example of the JSON syntax to pass the entire model back to the controller from JavaScript?  Thanks very much.  I'm from the US, but watch a lot of UK TV, listen to UK music, etc.

Comment: I live in the UK, but I'm Italian/Brazilian. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you can do it calling an AJAX POST:

**JS (using jQuery):**

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    // Stop the default submission
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize (JSON) the form's contents and post it to your action
    $.post('YourAction', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        // If you want to do something after the post
    });
});
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult YourAction(string JSONmodel)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    MyModel model = serializer.Deserialize(JSONmodel, typeof(MyModel));

    // Now you can do whatever you want with your model
}
```

**UPDATE**

For more complex objects, you can use a third part solution for serialization/deserialization. It's well documented and broaden used:

**Json.NET**: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why not use the default model binder?

Comment: Maybe the OP wants to submit something in a different way, to a different Action. Who knows?

Comment: I needed something similar when using the jQuery jqGrid, as an example. I couldn't rely on the default model binder to achieve the result expected.

Comment: i use this method for posting my knockout js viewmodels sometimes. its handy when making single page apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want something like this:  $('#MyDropdownList').change(function () { // post entire "model" back to controller perhaps by Jason});   //  the controller will return to another page so not wanting ajax here though some readers might

Comment: Extra credit:  I am currently keeping my javascript in its own .js file so I use syntax like:  var url = MyControllerUrlSettings.MyControllerPrepareModifyAssetInfoUrl;
                window.location.href = url.replace('__param__', trimmedAssetNbrString);  // it'd be nice to do in .js file but I can always do in .cshtml file if need be

Comment: The only differences are that you want a different element to submit and this would happen on a different event. You'll be using AJAX anyway. JSON is a format (object serialized into string). On the Action you just return the desired view.

Comment: Something like: `$('#dropdown').on('change'...` and `$('form').serialize()`. That's all you'd need to change.

Comment: OK, I am trying the syntax is my javascript for the dropdown change.    var ourModel = $('form').serialize();   The serialize function itself works correctly; however when I do:  var urlNew = url.replace('__param__', ourModel); the result looks correct, and I do window.location.href = urlNew; to transfer out of javascript to the controller.  However, on the controller side, the string representing the model is severely truncated.

Comment: I also eventually get a run-time error in the computer when I run serializer.Deserialize on the truncated string.  I'm not sure if this error is from the string being truncated or a separate error.

Comment: Note:  For complicated models with more than a few fields, the serialization / deserialization problem can be serious.  It is possible custom code is required; I haven't researched it.  It would sure be nice if the framework would just lift an object from the page to the control but that may only be possible via "submit"...

Comment: I have been using MVC since version one (4 years+ now) and I have never had any issues with using complex view models with dozens of fields and multiple objects - I also regularly use serialize() to post ajax data and I always use the Controllers model binder I never have to deserialize it manually. Very occasionally I have to exclude an Entity Framework navigation property but that's not often.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in a simpler way.

1. Alternate of example provided by MelanciUK.

   ```
   $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
       // Stop the default submission
          event.preventDefault();

      // User same property name as in Model
         $.post('YourAction', {prop1 : 'a', prop2 : 'b'}, function (data) {
      // If you want to do something after the post
   });
   ```

   });

   ```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SampleAction(SampleModel sModel)
     {

     }
   ```

You can achieve the same thing by stadard MVC(ModelBinding) convention i.e. no need to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: I haven't personally verified the above, but it looks very helpful.  If anyone wants to try it, please post whether it actually works or not.

Comment: Property data is not passing to controller.